# Create Tree Query From Numeric Mapping Table in SQL

Tags: t-sql, tree, hierarchical-data

I have an exported table from accounting software like below.

```
 AccountID     AccountName    
 ---------     -----------
 11            Acc11
 12            Acc12
 13            Acc13
 11/11         Acc11/11
 11/12         Acc11/12
 11/111        Acc11/111
 11/11/001     Acc11/11/001
 11/11/002     Acc11/11/002
 12/111        Acc12/111
 12/112        Acc12/112
```

then I want to convert it to tree query in MS-Sql Server 2008 to use as a Treelist datasource in my win aaplication.

Expected SQL query Result:

```
 AccountID     AccountName    ID   ParentID  Level   HasChild
 ---------     -----------    ---  --------- ------  --------
 11            Acc11          1     Null       1        1
 12            Acc12          2     Null       1        1
 13            Acc13          3     Null       1        0
 11/11         Acc11/11       4     1          2        1
 11/12         Acc11/12       5     1          2        0
 11/111        Acc11/111      6     1          2        0
 11/11/001     Acc11/11/001   7     4          3        0
 11/11/002     Acc11/11/002   8     4          3        0
 12/111        Acc12/111      9     2          2        0
 12/112        Acc12/112      10    2          2        0
```

Would you please help me for creating SQL query?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: it is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No doubts,whatever query you write or whatever DBA DO,your query will be slow because of faulty table structure.

I believe your above query is working fine for other sample data also.

In such situation,I fetch my record in front end like (c# etc) and do manipulation there in order to get desire output,it is often fast in such cases.

I have tried to write query in my own way,hope it is fast for 6000 records.Also please test my query for other sample data also.

I find LASTINdexOf("/") then join

```
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(50) = '11/11/001'
DECLARE @FindChar1 VARCHAR(1) = '/'

SELECT substring (@FilePath,0, LEN(@FilePath) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar1,REVERSE(@FilePath))+1 )AS LastOccuredAt
```

Final query,

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id int identity(1,1), AccountID  VARCHAR(100), AccountName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 ('11','Acc11')
,('12','Acc12')
,('13','Acc13')
,('11/11','Acc11/11')
,('11/12','Acc11/12')
,('11/111','Acc11/111')
,('11/11/001','Acc11/11/001')
,('11/11/002','Acc11/11/002')
,('12/111','Acc12/111')
,('12/112','Acc12/112');


DECLARE @FindChar VARCHAR(1) = '/'


    SELECT a.id
        ,a.accountid
        ,a.AccountName
        ,(
            SELECT min(c.id)
            FROM @tbl c
            WHERE c.id < a.id
                AND substring(a.accountid, 0, LEN(a.accountid) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar, REVERSE(a.accountid)) + 1) = c.accountid
            ) ParentID
        ,LEN(a.AccountID) - LEN(REPLACE(a.AccountID, '/', '')) + 1 AS [level]
        ,(
            SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN min(c.id) IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END
            FROM @tbl c
            WHERE c.id > a.id
                AND substring(c.accountid, 0, LEN(c.accountid) - CHARINDEX(@FindChar, REVERSE(c.accountid)) + 1) = a.accountid
            ) Haschild
    FROM @tbl a
    INNER JOIN @tbl b ON a.id = b.id + 1
```

Comment: Hello again, I found tow problem in the query. 1- if data be in deferment sort and arrangement, query will return wrong answer. 2-data regarding to first record eliminate in result set ('11','Acc11'). would you please check it?

Comment: @R.Salehi , its been very long.you can post sample data that return wrong answer and also do not remove above sample data.Secondly I reply it on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look on `HIERARCHYID`... 
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-use-SQL-Server-2008-hierarchyid-data-type

But this was an approach...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE( AccountID  VARCHAR(100), AccountName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 ('11','Acc11')
,('12','Acc12')
,('13','Acc13')
,('11/11','Acc11/11')
,('11/12','Acc11/12')
,('11/111','Acc11/111')
,('11/11/001','Acc11/11/001')
,('11/11/002','Acc11/11/002')
,('12/111','Acc12/111')
,('12/112','Acc12/112');

WITH shreddAccountID AS
(
    SELECT AccountName,AccountID
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')),AccountID) AS ID
          ,LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')) + 1 As [Level]
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(AccountID,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Shredded
    FROM @tbl
)
,RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT AccountID,AccountName,ID,[Level],Shredded.value('/x[sql:column("Level")][1]','int') AS innerID,CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS ParentID 
    FROM shreddAccountID WHERE [Level]=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sa.AccountID,sa.AccountName,sa.ID,sa.[Level],sa.Shredded.value('/x[sql:column("sa.Level")][1]','int'),r.ID
    FROM RecursiveCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN shreddAccountID AS sa ON sa.Level=r.Level+1 
                                        AND r.innerID=sa.Shredded.value('/x[sql:column("sa.Level")-1][1]','int')
)
SELECT r.AccountID
      ,r.AccountName
      ,r.ID
      ,r.ParentID
      ,r.[Level]
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM RecursiveCTE AS x WHERE r.ID = x.ParentID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChild
FROM RecursiveCTE AS r
ORDER BY [Level],ParentID
```

The result

```
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| AccountID | AccountName  | ID | ParentID | Level | HasChild |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11        | Acc11        | 1  | NULL     | 1     | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 12        | Acc12        | 2  | NULL     | 1     | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 13        | Acc13        | 3  | NULL     | 1     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11/11     | Acc11/11     | 4  | 1        | 2     | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11/111    | Acc11/111    | 5  | 1        | 2     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11/12     | Acc11/12     | 6  | 1        | 2     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 12/111    | Acc12/111    | 7  | 2        | 2     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 12/112    | Acc12/112    | 8  | 2        | 2     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11/11/001 | Acc11/11/001 | 9  | 4        | 3     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
| 11/11/002 | Acc11/11/002 | 10 | 4        | 3     | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Tanks for your reply. I checked it. It's work but it is very very slow. For example for  top 500 records of my table, it takes 116 seconds and  I think with all of my records (approximate  6000) it is not applicable. Is there any faster solution?

Comment: @R.Salehi It's your structure which makes it slow... Actually I do have some ideas how to speed this up after some structural enhancements, but this is to much for here... I'd suggest you the following: As my answer solves the given question please vote it up and accept it. Than start a new question (something like *How can I change my table's structure to get a faster hierarchy relation?* with a link to this and you will get a helping armada within minutes.

Comment: Please check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730320/create-tree-query-from-numeric-mapping-table-in-sql-specific-format) for my new question that follow our problem. Thanks