# Create Tree Query From Numeric Mapping Table in SQL (Specific Format)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have an exported table from accounting software like below.

```
 AccountID     AccountName    
  ---------     -----------
  11            Acc11
  12            Acc12
  13            Acc13
  11/11         Acc11/11
  11/12         Acc11/12
  11/111        Acc11/111
  11/11/001     Acc11/11/001
  11/11/002     Acc11/11/002
  12/111        Acc12/111
  12/112        Acc12/112
```

I want to convert it to tree query in MS-SQL Server 2008 to use it as a Treelist datasource in my win aaplication.
***I raised this question before and it's answered with a way that it was very very slow for my big table with more than 5000 records ([Create Tree Query From Numeric Mapping Table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726611/create-tree-query-from-numeric-mapping-table-in-sql])).*** But I think counting "/" and separating AccountID field with "/" can solve my problem easier and very faster.
Anyway, My expected result must be like below:

```
   AccountID     AccountName    ID   ParentID  Level   HasChild
   ---------     -----------    ---  --------- ------  --------
   11            Acc11          1     Null       1        1
   12            Acc12          2     Null       1        1
   13            Acc13          3     Null       1        0
   11/11         Acc11/11       4     1          2        1
   11/12         Acc11/12       5     1          2        0
   11/111        Acc11/111      6     1          2        0
   11/11/001     Acc11/11/001   7     4          3        0
   11/11/002     Acc11/11/002   8     4          3        0
   12/111        Acc12/111      9     2          2        0
   12/112        Acc12/112      10    2          2        0
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my answer given in the first question...

It would be best, if your table would keep the relation data directly in indexed columns. Before you change your table's structure you might try this:

A table with test data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ( AccountID  VARCHAR(100), AccountName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 ('11','Acc11')
,('12','Acc12')
,('13','Acc13')
,('11/11','Acc11/11')
,('11/12','Acc11/12')
,('11/111','Acc11/111')
,('11/11/001','Acc11/11/001')
,('11/11/002','Acc11/11/002')
,('12/111','Acc12/111')
,('12/112','Acc12/112');
```

This will get the needed data into a newly created temp table called `#tempHierarchy`

```
SELECT AccountID
      ,AccountName
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')),AccountID) AS ID
      ,Extended.HierarchyLevel
      ,STUFF(
       (
         SELECT '/' + A.B.value('.','varchar(10)')
         FROM Extended.IDsXML.nodes('/x[position() <= sql:column("HierarchyLevel")]') AS A(B)
         FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,2,'') AS ParentPath
      ,Extended.IDsXML.value('/x[sql:column("HierarchyLevel")+1][1]','varchar(10)') AS ownID
      ,Extended.IDsXML.value('/x[sql:column("HierarchyLevel")][1]','varchar(10)') AS ancestorID
INTO #tempHierarchy
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')) + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
                  ,CAST('<x></x><x>' + REPLACE(AccountID,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS IDsXML) AS Extended
;
```

The intermediate result

```
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| AccountID | AccountName  | ID | HierarchyLevel | ParentPath | ownID | ancestorID |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11        | Acc11        | 1  | 1              |            | 11    |            |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 12        | Acc12        | 2  | 1              |            | 12    |            |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 13        | Acc13        | 3  | 1              |            | 13    |            |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11/11     | Acc11/11     | 4  | 2              | 11         | 11    | 11         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11/111    | Acc11/111    | 5  | 2              | 11         | 111   | 11         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11/12     | Acc11/12     | 6  | 2              | 11         | 12    | 11         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 12/111    | Acc12/111    | 7  | 2              | 12         | 111   | 12         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 12/112    | Acc12/112    | 8  | 2              | 12         | 112   | 12         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11/11/001 | Acc11/11/001 | 9  | 3              | 11/11      | 001   | 11         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
| 11/11/002 | Acc11/11/002 | 10 | 3              | 11/11      | 002   | 11         |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

And now a similar recursive approach takes place as in my first answer. But - as it is using a real table now and all the string splitting has taken place already - it should be faster...

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT th.*
           ,CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS ParentID 
           ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.ParentPath=th.AccountID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChild
    FROM #tempHierarchy AS th WHERE th.HierarchyLevel=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sa.AccountID
          ,sa.AccountName
          ,sa.ID
          ,sa.HierarchyLevel
          ,sa.ParentPath
          ,sa.ownID
          ,sa.ancestorID
          ,(SELECT x.ID FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.AccountID=sa.ParentPath)
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.ParentPath=sa.AccountID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChild
    FROM RecursiveCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN #tempHierarchy AS sa ON sa.HierarchyLevel=r.HierarchyLevel+1 
                                       AND r.AccountID=sa.ParentPath
)
SELECT r.AccountID
      ,r.AccountName
      ,r.ID
      ,r.ParentID
      ,r.HierarchyLevel
      ,r.HasChild
FROM RecursiveCTE AS r
ORDER BY HierarchyLevel,ParentID;
```

And finally I clean up

```
DROP TABLE #tempHierarchy;
```

And here's the final result

```
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| AccountID | AccountName  | ID | ParentID | HierarchyLevel | HasChild |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11        | Acc11        | 1  | NULL     | 1              | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 12        | Acc12        | 2  | NULL     | 1              | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 13        | Acc13        | 3  | NULL     | 1              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11/11     | Acc11/11     | 4  | 1        | 2              | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11/111    | Acc11/111    | 5  | 1        | 2              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11/12     | Acc11/12     | 6  | 1        | 2              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 12/111    | Acc12/111    | 7  | 2        | 2              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 12/112    | Acc12/112    | 8  | 2        | 2              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11/11/001 | Acc11/11/001 | 9  | 4        | 3              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 11/11/002 | Acc11/11/002 | 10 | 4        | 3              | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+----+----------+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's work for all of my records in 14 seconds perfectly. Best regards.

Comment: Hi. I Have another problem with this. In my source Table (Firs table in this post) there is another field, named "SourceCast" therefore the query must give me several Tree. In other word, root node of my tree must be "SourceCast" and then its Child nodes must be "AccountID". Please help me again. Thanks

Comment: I created new question for this in:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948058/create-tree-query-from-numeric-mapping-table-in-sql-with-seperator-field