# Create Tree Query From Numeric Mapping Table in SQL (With Seperator Field)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, tree, treeview, hierarchical-data

I have an exported table from my accounting software like below in SQL Server 2008.

```
AccountID     AccountName     SourceCast     
---------     -----------     -----------
11            Acc11           9401
12            Acc12           9401
13            Acc13           9401
11/11         Acc11/11        9401
11/12         Acc11/12        9401
11/111        Acc11/111       9401
11/11/001     Acc11/11/001    9401
11/11/002     Acc11/11/002    9401
15            Acc15           9402
12            Acc12           9402
13            Acc13           9402
15/15         Acc15/15        9402
15/12         Acc15/12        9402
15/111        Acc15/111       9402
15/15/001     Acc15/15/001    9402
15/15/002     Acc15/15/002    9402
```

Then expected result must be like below:

```
 AccountID     AccountName    ID   ParentID  Level   HasChild  SourceCast
 ---------     -----------    ---  --------- ------  --------  ----------
 9401          9401           1     Null       1        1      9401
 11            Acc11          2     1          2        1      9401
 12            Acc12          3     1          2        1      9401
 13            Acc13          4     1          2        0      9401
 11/11         Acc11/11       5     2          3        1      9401
 11/12         Acc11/12       6     2          3        0      9401
 11/111        Acc11/111      7     2          3        0      9401
 11/11/001     Acc11/11/001   8     5          4        0      9401
 11/11/002     Acc11/11/002   9     5          4        0      9401
 12/111        Acc12/111      10    5          3        0      9401
 12/112        Acc12/112      11    5          3        0      9401
 9402          9402           12    Null       1        1      9401
 15            Acc15          13    12         2        1      9402
 12            Acc12          14    12         2        1      9402
 13            Acc13          15    12         2        0      9402
 15/15         Acc15/15       16    13         2        1      9402
 15/12         Acc15/12       17    13         2        0      9402
 15/111        Acc15/111      18    13         3        0      9402
 15/15/001     Acc15/15/001   19    16         4        0      9402
 15/15/002     Acc15/15/002   20    16         4        0      9402
 12/111        Acc12/111      21    14         3        0      9402
 12/112        Acc12/112      22    14         3        0      9402
```

This question raised before without "SourceCast" field in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730320/create-tree-query-from-numeric-mapping-table-in-sql-specific-format) and answered by [Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo). My main table is very large and it has more than 30000 records.
Would you please help me?
Thanks.

You can find my sample table here:

```
 CREATE TABLE Account(AccountID   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,AccountName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,SourceCast  INTEGER  NOT NULL);

 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11',N'Acc11',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'12',N'Acc12',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'13',N'Acc13',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11',N'Acc11/11',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/12',N'Acc11/12',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/111',N'Acc11/111',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11/001',N'Acc11/11/001',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11/002',N'Acc11/11/002',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15',N'Acc15',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'12',N'Acc12',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'13',N'Acc13',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15',N'Acc15/15',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/12',N'Acc15/12',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/111',N'Acc15/111',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15/001',N'Acc15/15/001',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15/002',N'Acc15/15/002',9402);
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I made some changes to my question. I hope my changes makes it better. Thanks

Comment: You've added the `SourceCast` column, but provided no explanation of what is to be done with it (or anything else). You provide a link to a prior question, but it seems quite different. For example, there is a one-to-one relationship between input and (expected) result rows in the linked question. This question has `AccountId` values like `12/111` and `12/112` appearing from the aether. Can you explain, in detail, how to create the expected results from your sample data? Perhaps then we can assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close... But I must admit, that I do not fully understand the logic... Why is there at 9401/Acc12 the "HasChild" set to 1 ?

Try it with this. The numbering is partitioned by the SourceCast. That means, that both sets (or many sets are treated as one set each, depending on the SourceCast. Additionally there is a running ID, like in your example:

```
CREATE TABLE Account(AccountID   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,AccountName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,SourceCast  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (AccountID,SourceCast));

 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11',N'Acc11',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'12',N'Acc12',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'13',N'Acc13',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11',N'Acc11/11',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/12',N'Acc11/12',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/111',N'Acc11/111',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11/001',N'Acc11/11/001',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'11/11/002',N'Acc11/11/002',9401);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15',N'Acc15',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'12',N'Acc12',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'13',N'Acc13',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15',N'Acc15/15',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/12',N'Acc15/12',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/111',N'Acc15/111',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15/001',N'Acc15/15/001',9402);
 INSERT INTO Account(AccountID,AccountName,SourceCast) VALUES (N'15/15/002',N'Acc15/15/002',9402);
GO

WITH DistinctSourceCasts AS (SELECT DISTINCT SourceCast FROM Account)
SELECT *
INTO #tempHierarchy
FROM
(
    SELECT SourceCast
          ,CAST(SourceCast AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS AccountID 
          ,CAST(SourceCast AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS AccountName
          ,0 AS ID
          ,0 AS HierarchyLevel
          ,'' AS ParentPath
          ,'' AS ownID
          ,'' AS ancestorID 
    FROM DistinctSourceCasts
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SourceCast
          ,AccountID
          ,AccountName
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SourceCast ORDER BY LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')),AccountID) AS ID
          ,Extended.HierarchyLevel
          ,STUFF(
           (
             SELECT '/' + A.B.value('.','varchar(10)')
             FROM Extended.IDsXML.nodes('/x[position() <= sql:column("HierarchyLevel")]') AS A(B)
             FOR XML PATH('')
           ),1,2,'') AS ParentPath
          ,Extended.IDsXML.value('/x[sql:column("HierarchyLevel")+1][1]','varchar(10)') AS ownID
          ,Extended.IDsXML.value('/x[sql:column("HierarchyLevel")][1]','varchar(10)') AS ancestorID
    FROM Account
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEN(AccountID)-LEN(REPLACE(AccountID,'/','')) + 1 AS HierarchyLevel
                      ,CAST('<x></x><x>' + REPLACE(AccountID,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS IDsXML) AS Extended
) AS tbl;

UPDATE #tempHierarchy SET ParentPath = SourceCast,ancestorID=SourceCast WHERE HierarchyLevel=1;
UPDATE #tempHierarchy SET ownID=SourceCast WHERE HierarchyLevel=0;


WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT th.*
           ,CAST(NULL AS BIGINT) AS ParentID 
           ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.ParentPath=th.AccountID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChild
    FROM #tempHierarchy AS th WHERE th.HierarchyLevel=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.SourceCast
          ,sa.AccountID
          ,sa.AccountName
          ,sa.ID
          ,sa.HierarchyLevel
          ,sa.ParentPath
          ,sa.ownID
          ,sa.ancestorID
          ,(SELECT x.ID FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.AccountID=sa.ParentPath)
          ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #tempHierarchy AS x WHERE x.ParentPath=sa.AccountID) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasChild
    FROM RecursiveCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN #tempHierarchy AS sa ON sa.HierarchyLevel=r.HierarchyLevel+1 
                                       AND r.AccountID=sa.ParentPath
                                       AND r.SourceCast=sa.SourceCast
)
SELECT SourceCast
      ,r.AccountID
      ,r.AccountName
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SourceCast,HierarchyLevel,ParentID,ID) AS ID
      ,r.ID AS GroupedID
      ,r.ParentID
      ,r.HierarchyLevel
      ,r.HasChild
FROM RecursiveCTE AS r

DROP TABLE #tempHierarchy;
```

The result:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| SourceCast | AccountID | AccountName  | ID | GroupedID | ParentID | HierarchyLevel | HasChild |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 9401      | 9401         | 1  | 0         | NULL     | 0              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11        | Acc11        | 2  | 1         | 0        | 1              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 12        | Acc12        | 3  | 2         | 0        | 1              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 13        | Acc13        | 4  | 3         | 0        | 1              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11/11     | Acc11/11     | 5  | 4         | 1        | 2              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11/111    | Acc11/111    | 6  | 5         | 1        | 2              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11/12     | Acc11/12     | 7  | 6         | 1        | 2              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11/11/001 | Acc11/11/001 | 8  | 7         | 4        | 3              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9401       | 11/11/002 | Acc11/11/002 | 9  | 8         | 4        | 3              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 9402      | 9402         | 10 | 0         | NULL     | 0              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 12        | Acc12        | 11 | 1         | 0        | 1              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 13        | Acc13        | 12 | 2         | 0        | 1              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15        | Acc15        | 13 | 3         | 0        | 1              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15/111    | Acc15/111    | 14 | 4         | 3        | 2              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15/12     | Acc15/12     | 15 | 5         | 3        | 2              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15/15     | Acc15/15     | 16 | 6         | 3        | 2              | 1        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15/15/001 | Acc15/15/001 | 17 | 7         | 6        | 3              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
| 9402       | 15/15/002 | Acc15/15/002 | 18 | 8         | 6        | 3              | 0        |
+------------+-----------+--------------+----+-----------+----------+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your attentions again. I am working on a budget and cash flow control software for several projects in the company that i work. Main data comes from accounting software like my sample.

Comment: @R.Salehi If performance matters (as it looked like in your last question) you might think about a trigger, to write the information I produce into the `#tempHierarchy`-table immediately when you insert or change the data. You might measure the time of step 1 (creating the temp table and step 2 (the recursive SELECT). With pre-calculated data you would reduce the time as step1 would be ommited. Does this work for you?

Comment: @R.Salehi, I edited my answer... To be honest: This data structure is really awful... This tiny change makes it even worse... Why do you need all this in one SELECT? Such things are done in the application layer normally... If this is a "real" hierarchy, there should be a clear dedicated column to get the structure from and not a string, which needs parsing, to get this information... Anyway, Happy Coding!

Comment: May I have your E-Mail address to sending my sample data to you? The query doesn't work with my data and i can not find the problem. (r.salehi.m@gmail.com)